# Memory allocation for strings of array

Tags: c, memory, allocation

I need to parse csv file. I create array of strings and allocating memory for that
The first cycle while(fgets(line,100,fp) is succesful, but when it enters the second the values are overwritten by the data of line

```
while (fgets(line, 100, fp))
{
    num_of_string++;
    code = (char **)realloc(code, sizeof(char *) * (num_of_string));
    occupation = (char **)realloc(occupation, sizeof(char *) * (num_of_string));
    num_of_ppl = (char **)realloc(num_of_ppl, sizeof(char *) * (num_of_string));
    
    char * column = strtok(line, ",");
    code[num_of_string-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(column)+1));
    code[num_of_string-1] = column;
    counter++;
    while (column)
    {
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            column = strtok(NULL, "\"");
            occupation[num_of_string-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(column)+1));
            occupation[num_of_string-1] = column;
            counter++;
            column = strtok(NULL, ",");
        } else if (counter == 2) {
            num_of_ppl[num_of_string-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(column)+1));
            num_of_ppl[num_of_string-1] = column;
            counter++;
            column = strtok(NULL, ",");
        } else {
            column = strtok(NULL, ",");
            counter++;
        }
    }
    counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: If one of the answers solved your issues, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Error is here:

```
code[num_of_string-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(column)+1));
code[num_of_string-1] = column;
```

The second assignment overwrites the dedicated allocated block with a pointer to data pointed by `column`. And those data are overwritten whenever a new line is parsed.

I suggest using `strdup()` to allocate a buffer and make a copy of the string.

Just replace the two lines above with:

```
code[num_of_string-1] = strdup(column);
```

There are similar errors for arrays `occupation` and `num_of_pll`.

Comment: Note: `strdup()` not part of the standard C library yet, but likely will be with C2X (2023?).

Answer (score 0):

```c
            column = strtok(NULL, "\"");
            occupation[num_of_string-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(column)+1));
            occupation[num_of_string-1] = column;
```

Pointer `column` points into your buffer `line` that is common for all lines you read from the file.
You allocate memory for the token but then you assign `column` creating a memory leak as you cannot free the allocated memory any longer.
By assigning pointers into the same buffer to all your array entries you will spoil old entries.

That is not how copying a string works.
You need to use `strcpy` instead:

```c
            column = strtok(NULL, "\"");
            occupation[num_of_string-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(column)+1));
            strcpy(occupation[num_of_string-1], column);
```

You should also check every return value for `NULL` pointers.